# Ad hoc installation of OUR APP in OUR IPad ... limitations

Tags: ipad, provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

We are developing an IPad app for in house use so we will use Apple's ad hoc installation. We will pay the $99 fee and install the app on no more than 100 IPads during one year.

Somebody over at MacRumors said that the app will be disabled after a "few" months. Is that true and if yes, how long is a "few" months? Ambiguous.

Once OUR APP is installed in OUR IPad, do we have to pay $99 in following years to keep OUR APP enabled in OUR IPAD? If yes, then it's like Apple grabbing ownership of OUR APP and leasing it back to US ... ludicrous.

Answer (score 0):

Your app wont be disabled but your provision to install the app will be, but it is very simple to renew it. (and i think its for 3 months).
And yes, you will have to pay the 99$ every year.

it will be cheeper for you to upload the app to the app store, and just mark it to not be shown in the store.